# Calculate current stock using SUM function

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate total purchase stock, cunsume stock, and current stock with its unit.  Im using the sqlquery below which gives wrong result.

I Have 3 different tables 1 . Purchase() contains purchase records 2. Consumption(contains consumption records) 3. Kichen items (contains name of different kichen items and its unit)

.  Im using the sqlquery below which gives wrong result.

```
select  k.Data as 'Item Name', SUM(p.Quantity) as 'Purchased Stock', SUM(DISTINCT c.Used_Quantity) as 'Cunsumed Stock', (SUM(p.Quantity)- SUM(DISTINCT c.Used_Quantity)) as 'Current Stock', k.Unit 
from kichenitems k, dailyCunsumtion c, dailyPurchase p 
where  c.Item_Name=p.Item_Name and k.Data =p.Item_Name and k.Data =c.Item_Name 
group by k.Data,k.Unit
```

It gives wrong result tell me tell me correct one so i cant get all items names with total purchase stock , total consumption, and Current stock with its appropriate unit.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: _"It gives wrong result tell me tell me correct one"_ - made my day. Wrong how?

Comment: You are using old and unadvised syntax for connecting tables. Read about JOINs.

Comment: Without sample data and desired output, and what is wrong with the current output, it is not clear what you want. However, the use of `distinct` on a quantity seems wrong. Remove both of those.

Answer (score 0):

You have to isolate the distinct records from dailyCunsumtion in a subquery - then you can SUM them in your outer query.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  k.Data as 'Item Name'
, SUM(p.Quantity) as 'Purchased Stock'
, SUM(c.Used_Quantity) as 'Cunsumed Stock'
, SUM(p.Quantity - c.Used_Quantity) as 'Current Stock'
, k.Unit 
FROM kichenitems k
INNER JOIN dailyPurchase p            
       AND p.Item_Name = k.Data      
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Item_Name
                          , Used_Quantity
                       FROM dailyCunsumtion) c                  
                         ON c.Item_Name = p.Item_Name    
GROUP BY k.Data, k.Unit
```

Comment: This gives Wrong  Result as same used stock counts Repetaidly.

Comment: In that case, I will have to defer to those who commented on the question itself: you need to add sample data and the desired outcome if you want to have your question answered.